# when should we use (_, args) =>

Tags: c#, lambda, event-handling, anonymous-function

by chance, I found this type of code

```
     public void AddAnimation(Button button)
    {
        //some code here 

        button.MouseHover += (_, args) =>
        {
            contractTimer.Stop();
            expandTimer.Start();
            animationStarted = DateTime.Now;
            button.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
        };

       //other code here
    }
```

what I know, if we want to add an event we use

```
    private void Control_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //some code here
    }
```

can anyone please explain to me why they used `button.MouseHover += (_, args) => ...`.

Comment: The whole business from the `(_, args)` through the `};` is a lambda expression, which is just a way to create an anonymous function.  They are using weird names for the arguments, but the names don't really matter.

Comment: When you want to, this just a lambda expression with two parameters. Personally I don't find the name "_" very meaningful.

Comment: Actually the real question was __why__ they use a lambda __in the first place__ and that is not explained or even mentioned in the linked post. So (once again) __not really a duplicate__. - One of the advantages of using a __lambda__ is that it can make use of all the variables and parameters that are available in the code that creates it.